Integral of $\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^{\frac52}}\,dx$
I'm trying to apply the Chebyshev substitution (it is a binomial of the form $x^m(a+bx^n)^p$ with $m=-\frac{5}{2}$, $a=1$, $b=1$, $n=2$, $p=\frac{1}{2}$) https://www.creative-mathematics.cunbm.utcluj.ro/wp-content/uploads/1994_vol_03/creative_1994_3_099_104_abstract.pdf.
But conditions are not satisfied, so this integral can't be represented in terms of elementary functions.
However, I doubt, because the integral of $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}$ clearly has an elementary antiderivative and by applying substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$, we get $\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{u^{\frac{5}{2}}}$.
How do I handle this integral?

$$I=\int\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}\,dx$$
Apply $\frac{1}{x}=u\implies dx=\frac{-1}{u^2}\,du$
$$I=-\int\frac{\sqrt{1+u}}{u^2}\,du$$
and not
$$I=\int\frac{\sqrt{1+u}}{u^{\frac{5}{2}}}\,du$$
You can solve $I=-\int\frac{\sqrt{1+u}}{u^2}\,du$ using by-parts and then using standard integrals.

I've confused $\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{x}}$ with $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}$. The former doesn't have an elementary antiderivative.

@eMathHelp, yes, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5Bx%2BDivide%5B1%2Cx%5D%5D%2Cx%5D

Making the problem more general
$$I_n=\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^{\frac{2n+1}2}}\,dx$$ does not show solution in terms of elementary function.
$$x=\sqrt t \quad \implies \quad I_n=\frac 12\int\frac{\sqrt{1+t}}{t^{\frac{2n+3}4}}\,dt$$ which is the definition of a Gaussian hypergeometric fonction
$$I_n=-\frac{2}{(2 n-1)\, t^{\frac{2 n-1}{4}}}\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-2 n}{4} ;\frac{5-2 n}{4} ;-t\right)$$
As a series
$$\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-2 n}{4} ;\frac{5-2 n}{4} ;-t\right)=$$ $$\frac{2n-1} {2\sqrt \pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \,\frac{\Gamma \left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right) } {(4k+1-2n)\,k! }\, t^k$$
Edit
We face an alternating series. If $a_k$ is the summand
$$\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=1-\frac{5}{2
   k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$
